# How can I attach an EBS Volume to an EMR Cluster using the AWS Data Pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

AWS have recently provided the possibility to attach an EBS volume to specific cluster instance types like m4's.  Whilst it is possible to attach an EBS volume using EMR, I cannot seem to find a way to do so via the AWS Data Pipeline. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ran into the same situation. Our AWS contacts confirmed that this is not currently supported. You can, however, spin-up your own EMR cluster with attached EBS volume and have Data Pipeline use that cluster (via workgroup). This is less convenient but possibly a workable solution.

Comment: You're right.  Just found out that at least the instances come with a default 32Gb attached EBS volume.